Why can't I move my camera while in camera mode?
I just started a new project and for some reason when I'm in camera mode, there's no square/rectangle to show what would be in the rendered view and I can't move the camera in camera mode. I can move the camera outside of camera mode by selecting it but I can only move it in kind of a rudimentary way. How do I fix this?
I've included a screenshot of my navigation settings. Please let me know if you need more information, as I'm new to Blender.




Do you actually have a camera in your scene? - It should have an entry in the top-right Outliner and clicking it should hilight it in the 3D view. Might be an idea to add a screenshot of your full Blender window which you can do via the Window > Save Screenshot menu and then edit it into your question. Also please share your Blend file which you can do via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Yes, I do have a camera in my scene.

I uploaded the Blend file.

Switch to camera view and disable the Lock Camera View button:

In the previous versions of Blender the option is available in the N panel > View > View Lock:

Then unzoom until you see the camera borders:

At last, reactivate the Lock Camera View button.

For some reason the lock isn't showing up on my screen. Any ideas?

Please see my edit

@Philadelphia_Collins83 The lock icon was introduced in Blender 4.1 I think. You're using 4.02.

Camera to view is already checked in my file. Perhaps it is because I'm not using the latest version of Blender. If I download the latest version, will I lose my project? Otherwise is there any other way to fix my issue?

Uncheck, zoom out, check again

I ended up starting a new project and appending the objects already made because everything disappeared for some reason. No camera issues. Thank you everyone for your input!
